# Adding tooltips in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem assigning a tooltip to a `glyphicon`.

I had a look at this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9Ku6/3/)**, but it is not applicable for my case since I am using `jQuery` to create the `HTML` elements like this:

```
var trashIcon = $('<i>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-trash');
```

Now I want to wrap the following code to match the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9Ku6/3/)** link... but how can I do this?

```
var trashToolTip = $('<a>').addClass=('my-tool-tip').attr({ data-toggle:"tooltip" data-placement:"left" title:"Delete" });
```

**CSS**:

```
a.my-tool-tip, a.my-tool-tip:hover, a.my-tool-tip:visited {
    color: black;
}
```

**EDIT:**

As seen in the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9Ku6/3/)** link:

> The class CANNOT be tooltip...

`var trashIcon` looks like this in when parsed into HTML:

```
`<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>`
```

I want the HTML version of `var trashToolTip`, which is the following, to be *parent* (better term?):

`<a class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="delete"></a>`

So that it should look like the following code:

```
<a class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="delete">
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Are you able to create a jsFiddle that is applicable to what you're doing?  From the question, it is not very clear.  Specifically "Now I want to wrap this around to match the jsFiddle linked above".

Comment: For one, you have invalid HTML.  The `<input>` element is not a container so there is no such thing as a `</input>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function to achieve that HTML structure. You'd use it like:

```
trashIcon.wrap(trashToolTip);
```